# Running a media scan on files created by background process

Tags: android, mtp, android-mediascanner

As outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54930607/2703209), I am mirroring the logcat output of my app with this call:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -f " + absolutePathToLogFile);
```

This will spawn a logcat process which duplicates log entries to the file I specify in real time. The process never exits by itself but is terminated if the app process exits or is killed.

In order for the resulting file to be visible via MTP (without needing to reboot), I need to run a media scan on it.

If I trigger the media scan right after spawning the logcat process, the file shows up but MTP clients will only see the content that was there when the scan took place. Anything appended later is missing when accessing the file via MTP, though it is visible when accessing the file via `adb`.

I would therefore need to run the media scan **after** writing the last event to the file, i.e. after the logcat process has been killed. As I understand it, I cannot do that from within my app, as Android will kill app processes without warning and without giving apps a chance to react. That is, I cannot trigger a media scan when my app is about to get killed as the app won’t get told this is about to happen. I also cannot react to the death of the logcat process as my app will no longer be alive by then.

(I do realize that I may also need to scan the file before that, e.g. if I want to access the file while it’s still being written to, but that is a different story.)

I am aware that a media scan can be triggered via a shell command such as

```
am broadcast -a android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE -d file:///path/to/file
```

but have no idea how to get this to run after the logcat process has exited.

Is there any way I can tell the system run a media scan on the file after the logcat process has ended?